# Connection refused: Docker and Symfony

Tags: docker, symfony

I'm trying to connect my Symfony project with a database in a Docker environment but unfortunately, the message is always: Connection refused.

My .env configuration (Symfony file):

```
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_NAME=db
DATABASE_URL=mysql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
```

and my Docker-compose configuration:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    db:
        image: mariadb
        container_name: db-docker-env
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "db"
            MYSQL_USER: "root"
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
        networks:
            - dev
        command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
    
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin-docker-env
        restart: always
        depends_on: 
            - db
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: db
        networks:
            - dev
```

I searched for a long time on the Internet, but unfortunately to no avail. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: I am not clear on what you want to achieve. Connect from outside of the `dev` docker network to the DB or from within? Your database does not seem to export any ports like for instance `3306` and depending on the answer to above question you might need to adjust the `DB_HOST` parameter to `db-docker-env` when trying to connect from inside the docker network as `localhost` within a container is the container's own localhost, not the one of the host machine.

Comment: I would comment out enough config (in bundles.php & the config files) to start without a DB - and show what $_ENV['DATABASE_URL'] is. Knowing what you may be actually using as the DSN/URL can often be useful - if it's not as you expect.

Comment: @Mushroomator thanks for your reply, I had to change 127.0.0.1 with the name of the service ‘db‘